# Problems installing a windows service

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, service

I'm attempting to install a Windows Service. I've tried it from within Visual Studio 2010 and also by just double clicking the msi. I followed the walk through here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx

The problem seems to be an nhibernate mapping exception.

I have a class library with hbm.xml files (yes, they are included as resources) and my entity classes.

I don't understand what I need to do to deploy everything correctly.

Comment: I used these two tutorials in the past and never hard an issue.  Hope they help -- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C and  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3938/Creating-a-C-Service-Step-by-Step-Lesson-I

Comment: that second one is from 2003...I think a few things have changed since then don't you?

Comment: I used those links to install a .NET 4 service on a W2k8 server.  Things may very well have changed, but those links got the job done for me.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:  First, make sure your project type is a console application. That will ensure that your app.config is seen and renamed/copied correctly.  Second, the business of installing and uninstalling (the windows service) is really best done with an open source project called [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/).  I've personally had great experiences using TopShelf to bootstrap Windows Services.  The documentation is a little spartan but there is a [simple example](http://topshelf-project.com/documentation/getting-started/) to get you up and running quickly.  Simply put, it handles all of the messy plumbing to get the service installed and uninstalled by exposing a simple to use command line interface.